# How to find common objects in multiple lists?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of User objects (`List<User>`). Every object in this list has a list of events (`List<Event>`). I need to create a new collection of Events with the common objects in all lists of Events in every user. I mean every user in base collection has every event in new collection of Events.

I think it can be done using foreach loop, but I hope there is more elegant way to do this using LINQ.

Hope, you'll help. Thank you.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking for. Can you give an example of expected input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Enumerable.Interstect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) methods

```
// first get events for first user
IEnumerable<Event> seed = userList.First().Events;

// intersect with events for users (except the first)
var commonItems = userList.Skip(1).Aggregate(seed, (s, u) => s.Intersect(u.Events));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it says it cannot convert Generic.IEnumerable to Generic.List on Intersect method. Is there any way to fix it? s.Intersect(u.Events).ToList() is ok?

Comment: @АлексейЦветков-Омеличев Actually, rather than add `.ToList()` declare `seed` as `IEnumerable<T>` -- both work but the second option is more efficient. see my updated answer.

Comment: Maybe this can also be written (using the simplest overload of `Aggregate`) like: `var commonItems = userList.Select(u => u.Events).Aggregate((e, d) => e.Intersect(d));`. But actually it may be even more intuitive (and shorter) to substitute the last lambda with a direct method group, using the `Intersect` method as a usual static method (disregarding its extension method nature), like so: `var commonItems = userList.Select(u => u.Events).Aggregate(Enumerable.Intersect);`

Comment: @p.s.w.g one more question. How do I select these events depending on their Id (some property) equality?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to select all events in all users, then create groups of equal events, select only those groups with as many events as users, and then just one event for each of these groups.

```
var x = users.SelectMany(u => u.Events) // select all events at once
  .GroupBy(e => e) // group them
  .Where(g => g.Count() == users.Count) // select groups with as many events as users
  .Select(g => g.Key); // select just one event for each group (the others are the same)
```